# Meteor: Adding Fields on createAccount

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to use the Meteor Roles package: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles
to obviously create a new field in user model.

The user is created no problem but the 'roles' field I'm trying to define isn't created. I can add things like 'Profile' and details within that too. But for some reason I can't make a roles field. Here's my form:

```
Template.signup.events({
 'submit #signup-form' : function(e, t) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var roles = ['admin'],
       email = t.find('#email').value,
       password = t.find('#password').value;

   Accounts.createUser({email: email, password : password, roles: roles}, function(err){
       if (err) {
         alert("User Not Added")
       } else {
         console.log("User Added.")
       }

   });

 }
});
```

Eventually I'll need to publish this to the client but for right now I just want the field to show in MongoDb, which it's not.

3 things:

1. I feel like the code above should work but I'm clearly missing something
2. In the package docs it mentions this `Roles.addUsersToRoles` which I
   tried but no luck
3. Or do I need to possibly update the record, after it's been created?

I did go into the DB and manually added the field and associated string to update it (with $set) and it worked. But from the form itself though, no luck.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Accounts.createUser`](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser) function only lets you add arbitrary user properties via the `profile` option which is where they end up getting stored in mongo.  That is why Meteor is ignoring the `roles: roles` part of your `Accounts.createUser` call.

It is true that the `meteor-roles` package stores the list of roles assigned to a user directly in the users collection, but that is almost just an implementation detail and you are probably best off sticking to the API that `meteor-roles` provides for adding users to a role:

`Roles.addUsersToRoles(<userId>,[<list of roles>])`

The `userId` passed to `Roles.addUsersToRoles` is the value returned by `Accounts.createUser` when its called on the server which is probably where you want to be doing this as that feels way more secure.

Comment: Very well said. Thank you. For anyone following this, don't use userId as the variable name on the Roles.addUserToRoles. go-oleg isn't saying to, I just did because it made sense. However, that is reserved somewhere and even though I had everything set up correct it wasn't working until I changed the name,

Comment: @go-oleg is spot-on.  The example apps in the github repo show this in action: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/blob/master/examples/mini-pages/server/server.js#L57-L66

Answer (score 1):

The `Accounts.createUser` function only takes `username`, `email`, `password` and `profile` as params for the user object. [See the documentation here.](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser) So, to add another field to a new user object, you need to add it in a second step:

```
var uid = Accounts.createUser({email: email, password: password});
Meteor.users.update(uid, {$set: {roles: roles}});
```

Comment: Hubert OG you are a baller. I see your answers everywhere, thank you. I'll be using this info to allow the user to add to their profile if they so wish.